# HTML Anchors with classes or nodes

Tags: html, url

Is there any way to include something prefixed with `#` in a url that will jump to an element with a `class` attribute, not `id` or `name`?

I know that anchors are usually used for things like this:

```
<body>
    <a id="top"><!-- Header goes here --></a>
    ...
    <h2>Section Title</h2>&nbps;<a href="#top">Top</a>
</body>
```

But sometimes I want to link to a `div` on a page that has neither an `id` attribute nor a `name`.  Take for example the following page:

```
<html>
    ...
    <body>
        <!-- 2 to 3 screens' worth of content here -->
        ...
        <table class="t-blue">
            <!-- Relevant info -->
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I want to link directly to the able, is there any way to do so?  Maybe something like `http://some-site.com/index.html#.t-blue[0]` or `http://some-site.com/index.html#.table[0]`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `id`/`name` scrolling is on the browser level, but it doesn't support it with `class`, since the same `class` can be on multiple different elements (to which element would it scroll in that case?). You could implement it yourself, but why not use the more semantically correct `name` or `id` attributes that already has the support?

Comment: use ID for internal links. index.html#something will lead to #something id element on the page. You cannot link to the table the way you have it now. If you put an ID on it then sure page.html#tableID

Comment: @ajp15243 I would use `id` in a heartbeat, except I didn't write the page.  If you're curious, it's actually the table in [this subreddit's sidebar](http://reddit.com/r/iama).

Comment: @KevinOrr Oh God must resist Reddit link while at work... on a more serious note, if you are unable to change the markup, then the best option is to somehow get a JS solution that finds elements with that class, probably assume that the first one is the only one you want, and then scroll to that. I don't think you'll be able to execute said JS, however, if you're linking to an external page.

Comment: @ajp15243 Alrighty! Time to get XSS hacking!

Answer (score 0):

Not without JavaScript on the page with the anchor.

The `#` references are to named anchors, or ids because they are defined to be unique in the standard, and its the way the standard is written.

With JavaScript on the page with the, you could use the url in address bar, parse it and scroll to the element with that class. But if you have access to write JS to that page, why wouldn't just use the id or name?